# dig - answer section has list of server names

Tags: networking, dns, dig

this is the answer section of : `dig supl.nokia.com`

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
supl.nokia.com.     82858   IN  CNAME   nokia.supl.svc.ovi.com.
nokia.supl.svc.ovi.com. 58  IN  CNAME   nokia.supl.svc.ovi.com.glb.as1248.net.
nokia.supl.svc.ovi.com.glb.as1248.net. 300 IN CNAME geo3.nokia.supl.svc.ovi.com.glb.as1248.net.
geo3.nokia.supl.svc.ovi.com.glb.as1248.net. 60 IN CNAME supl.nokia.us-east-1.pos.here.com.
supl.nokia.us-east-1.pos.here.com. 100 IN CNAME pra-suplnokia-516311011.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
pra-suplnokia-516311011.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 52.3.37.45
pra-suplnokia-516311011.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 52.22.201.16
```

I was expecting an IP address like what I got for : `dig supl.google.com`

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
supl.google.com.    300 IN  A   74.125.195.192
```

What is this list of servers I got for nokia?

Answer (score 0):

It's a chain of `CNAME` pointers. If you look at the names on the right-hand side of the lines with "CNAME" in them, they are the same as the left-hand name on the following line, until you get to the final step where the right-hand name leads to two `A` records (which then hold the IP addresses you wanted).

Answer (score -1):

Are this names of different servers? Or same one?

Also, some other DNS server returns in its answer only 3 CNAMEs (and not this whole list) and I see in wireshark for the 3rd CMANE :

nokia.supl.svc.ovi.com.glb.as1248.net: type A, class IN, addr 127.0.0.1

(So i get localhost as my query result and can not establish connection)

How can that be? Why does it return only 3 and not the whole list, like i got when i did 'dig' command?

Thanks